# how to put NSString in NSLog with multiple arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nslog

when i try to use NSLog like:

```
NSLog(@"one" @"two" @"three");
```

this works and prints onetwothree in console. but when i try to use like this

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"three"];  
NSLog(@"one" @"two" s);
```

the above doesnt work and i get a compile time error that "Expected ')'". I am not sure what to do.

any help?

P.S. I am trying to use XcodeColors and I have to give arguments to NSLog like above. so don't answer that use it like below. I know this works. but I have to pass arguments to NSLog like above.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", @"one", @"two", @"three"];  
NSLog(s, nil);
```

**Edit**:

I can use NSLog like this to get my desired result:

```
NSString *s = @"ss";
NSLog(@"one" @"two" @"%@",s);
```

that leads to my another question. I want to make a macro for NSLog. the macro looks like:

```
LOG_X(val) NSLog(@"xx" @"yy" @"%@",val @"zz")
```

Now when the following works:

```
LOG_X(@"one")
LOG_X(@"one" @"two" @"three")
```

but following does not work

```
NSString *s = @"one two three";
LOG_X(s);
```

it gives me the same error "Expected ')'"

Comment: Where are you getting the second error?

Comment: i am getting error at LOG_X

Comment: i can only use @"%@",s at the last string. not in between thats why I am getting the error.

Comment: NSLog(@"x" @"%@",@"xx" @"xx") doesnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to print out the contents of an `NSString` variable in `NSLog`, you need to treat it like a formatted string.

So instead of:

`NSLog(@"one" @"two" s);`

Use:

`NSLog(@"one" @"two" @"%@", s);`

**ADDITION:**

You must insert the comma and `val` at the end of the macro. It should look like:

`#define LOG_X(val) NSLog(@"xx" @"yy" @"%@" @"zz", val)`.

Comment: thanx for the answer. this works that leads to my another question. please read my edit.

Comment: Why not define `LOG_X` as: `#define LOG_X(val) NSLog(@"xxyy%@zz", val)`? I don't understand the need to have all of the separate literals.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do it with variables: the reason it works with string literals is that when you write several literals separated by whitespace, the compiler combines them in a single string literals for you.

The solution that you have (with the format string for three %@ specifiers) is a good one.
You can also format the three values in a similar way.